# MySQL COUNT IF between multiple tables

Tags: mysql, join

I am trying to run a fairly simple count based on two MySQL tables but I can't get the syntax right.

```
         Table_1                                Table_2
Actor | Behavior | Receiver |       | Behavior | Type_of_behavior |
 Eric        a        ann                a            Good
 Eric        b        ann                b            Bad 
 Bob         a        Susan              a            Good
 Bob         c        Bob                c            shy
```

I want to `COUNT Table 1.Behavior` by `table_2.Type_of_behavior WHERE Table_1.Behavior = Table_2 Behavior` and `group by Table_1.Actor`. The syntax I've tried is below.
I realize I could join the tables, but for other reasons I need them separate.

```
SELECT actor, JOIN Table_1, Table_2
COUNT(IF(Table_2.Type_of_behavior = "good", 1,0))
 AS 'good' FROM Table_1.Behavior GROUP BY actor;
```

Comment: I'm not even sure this is possible WITHOUT joining or doing some sort of union. Joining would certainly make your life a whole lot easier. But it could be done through some sort of union of two select statements.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if this what you want, but here's something that you should be able to modify at least.

```
SELECT actor, COUNT(Type_of_behavior)
FROM table_1 JOIN table_2
ON table_1.behavior=table_2.behavior
WHERE Type_of_behavior = 'good'
GROUP BY actor
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT actor, 
       sum(t2.Type_of_behavior = 'good') AS good
from Table_1 t1
join Table_2 t2 on t1.behaviour = t2.behaviour
GROUP BY actor;
```